# How to add links to root resource in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest

How to expose an external resource (not managed through a repository) in the **root listing of resources** of Spring Data REST? I defined a controller following the pattern in [Restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentController.java)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be done by implementing `ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource>`.

Following code snippet adds "/others" to the root listing

```
@Controller
@ExposesResourceFor(Other.class)
@RequestMapping("/others")
public class CustomRootController implements
        ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Other>>> listEntities(
            Pageable pageable) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
            //... do what needs to be done
    }

    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource resource) {
        resource.add(ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(CustomRootController.class).withRel("others"));

        return resource;
    }
}
```

should add

```
{
    "rel": "others",
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/others"
}
```

to your root listing links

Comment: how can I do this for a non controller link? (specifically I want to add spring security logout)

Comment: @xenoterracide maybe with a  `@RequestMapping("/logout")` on the controller and then a `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) public logout(){ // do logout }` method. What do you mean non-controller link?

Comment: @aycanadal I'm fairly confident I figured that out at some point, but I have filter that I need to link to because, spring security

Comment: In case of repository is `@RepositoryRestController` or `@BasePathAwareController` it also missed and HAL entry point and couldn't be discoreved, so linkTo created from root ("/"). Are there any solution for this?

Comment: See also migration to Spring HATEOAS 1.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118868/migrating-resourceprocessor-to-hateoas-1-0-0-m1

Answer (score 2):

I have been searching for an answer to the same issue, but the key is: I don't have a controller. My url points to something created in an auth filter. What worked for me is to create a `RootController` that doesn't have any methods, and use it for building links in the `ResourceProcessor` implementation.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RootController {}
```

Then the link is inserted using the empty controller.

```
@Component
public class AuthLinkProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {

    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource resource) {
        resource.add(
                linkTo(RootController.class)
                .slash("auth/login")
                .withRel("auth-login"));
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2022, API has changed. This reply might be relevant: [Migrating ResourceProcessor to HATEOAS 1.0.0 M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118868/migrating-resourceprocessor-to-hateoas-1-0-0-m1).

Here's my piece of code with the new API:

```java
@Component
class AuthLinkProcessor implements RepresentationModelProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {
    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource model) {
        model.add(
                linkTo(AuthenticationController.class)
                        .slash("/authenticate")
                        .withRel("authenticate"));
        return model;
    }
}
```