# How to add custom links to non repository rest controller in spring data rest hal?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I would like to add custom rest controller to be added to the json/hal response of the entry point, together with all the respositories that are added by spring. I'm struggling with this by two problems:

1. How can I add my custom controller so it appears on the entry point together with the links to my repository?
2. How can I decorate with a link to my custom controller on a representation of an entity produced by the repository so I can link to my custom controller?

I have struggled for a while and created a [github project](https://github.com/niggusch/spring-data-rest-hal-custom) using spring-data-mongodb to demonstrate what I mean. There is one simple Entity `Invoice`and the `InvoiceRepository` which extends MongoRepository and has one special finder Method `List<Invoice> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName")String firstName);`. 
In addition there are two custom controller that I would like to be included in the `_links` section on the entry point of the service-

Using the Hal Browser, the entry point at the moment looks like

```
{
  "_links": {
    "invoices": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/invoices{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like it to be

```
  "_links": {
    "invoices": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/invoices{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "export": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/export/invoices"
    },
     "custom":{
      "href": "localhost:8080/customize/invoices/search/customList"
    }   
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/profile"
    }
  }
```

To the second part of my question, I have no Idea how to achieve.
The JSON representation of an invoice looks like

```
{
  "firstName": "Chuck",
  "lastName": "Noris",
  "amount": 2.5,
  "exported": false,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/invoices/27490450945023268364302849904"
    },
    "invoice": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/invoices/27490450945023268364302849904"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to extend it with custom export link to each invoice like this

```
{
  "firstName": "Chuck",
  "lastName": "Noris",
  "amount": 2.5,
  "exported": false,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/invoices/27490450945023268364302849904"
    },
    "invoice": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/invoices/27490450945023268364302849904"
    }
    "export": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/customize/export/invoice/27490450945023268364302849904"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Q1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135756/how-to-add-links-to-root-resource-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: Q2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292727/how-can-i-simply-add-a-link-to-a-spring-data-rest-entity

Comment: @AlanHay thanks, i'll try that. Sorry that I didn't  found this on stackoverflow by myself.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Alan the answers are already given on StackOverflow:

1. [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135756/how-to-add-links-to-root-resource-in-spring-data-rest)
2. [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292727/how-can-i-simply-add-a-link-to-a-spring-data-rest-entity)

For other readers I'have updated my Github Project with a sample implementation of both UseCases. Enjoy at [spring-data-rest-hal-custom](https://github.com/niggusch/spring-data-rest-hal-custom).