# How to extend existing links to resources with custom Spring Data Rest Controller

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using **Spring boot 1.5.10** with **spring-boot-starter-data-rest**.

I created domain entities:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String secondName;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Address address;

    ...

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Column
    private String build;

    ...

}
```

And I've created repositories for this domain entities:

```java
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    User getUserByFirstNameAndSecondName(String firstName, String secondName);

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    User getUserByAddress(Address address);


}
```

```java
interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, String> {

    Address getAddressByStreet(String street);

}
```

After that I give next HATEOAS root endpoints:

```json
{
  "_links" : {
    "users" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/address{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
}
```

And if I navigate to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users I'll get something like that:

```json
{
  "_links" : {
    "getUserByFirstNameAndSecondName" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/search/getUserByFirstNameAndSecondName{?firstName, secondName ,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/users/search"
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to add a new endpoint to "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/search" use a custom controller, with **@RepositoryRestController**, for example:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class UserRestController {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users/search/getUserByStreetAddress")
    public User getUserByStreetAddress(String street) {

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet(street);

        return userRepository.getUserByAddress(address);
    }

}
```

But my controller doesn't add anything to existing endpoints. 
I've read [How to add links to root resource in Spring Data REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135756/how-to-add-links-to-root-resource-in-spring-data-rest) and this decision works fine for root endpoints but I want add **getUserByStreetAddress** endpoint to **users/search** and eventually get the following:

```json
{
  "_links" : {
    "getUserByFirstNameAndSecondName" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/search/getUserByFirstNameAndSecondName{?firstName, secondName ,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },

    //Method from my custom controller added to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/search" endpoint
    "getUserByStreetAddress" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/search/getUserByStreetAddress{?street ,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/search"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `ResourceProcessor<RepositorySearchesResource>` and add the link manually.

```
// other imports here
import static org.springframework.hateoas.TemplateVariable.VariableType.REQUEST_PARAM;


@Component
public class RepositorySearchesResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<RepositorySearchesResource> {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryRestConfiguration restConfiguration;

    @Override
    public RepositorySearchesResource process(RepositorySearchesResource resource) {
        // early exit if we're not dealing with a User resource
        if (!User.class.equals(resource.getDomainType())) {
            return resource;
        }

        // add a custom link to /users/search
        String search = resource.getId().getHref();

        List<TemplateVariable> list = new ArrayList<>;
        list.add(new TemplateVariable("street", REQUEST_PARAM);
        boolean addProjection = restConfiguration.getProjectionConfiguration().hasProjectionFor(Parameter.class);
        if (addProjection) {
            // should be "projection" unless you configured it differently
            list.add(restConfiguration.getProjectionConfiguration().getParameterName());
        }

        TemplateVariables tvs = new TemplateVariables(list);

        Link link = new Link(new UriTemplate(search + "/getUserByStreetAddress", tvs"), "getUserByStreetAddress");
        resource.add(link);

        return resource;
}
```

I put in the RepositoryRestConfiguration and UriTemplate, so as to give a hint about adding other rest parameters (pagination, sorting...) later if necessary.

Comment: **Mark**, thank you for the solution.I'll try to do it. I found 2 more solutions when I can override existing methods from a repository in a custom controller with additional logic and second use ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> for registering custom methods to existing endpoints. I'll describe this below.